# Exclusion Filtering in Excel Advanced Filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I cannot get the advanced filter system on excel to exclude a set of criteria like I can include.

So this is the data I have in a table.
[image]

Now I click Filter, Advanced, and then under criteria I go into a new sheet with the same headers and the formulas ="<>Director", ="<>Vice President", etc

It looks like this

[image]

HOWEVER, it doesn't end up excluding the terms I list! When I do the opposite and use it for inclusion filtering it works like a charm. I just cannot get the opposite to work.

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to write the Criteria in another way, and if you want to include Director ...(each Title starting by Director) and the same for Vice President use:

```
Title           Title            Title                  Title  
<>*Director*    <>*Manager*     <>Vice President*       <>VP*
```

Because you need only the Titles that are <>Director* and <>Manager* and <>Vice President*
When you write in 2 Rows it means OR
In 2 columns it means And

If you want to copy to another sheet:

- Start the Advanced Filter from the sheet which you want to copy to
- Click on copy to another Location
- In copy to box select the cell where you want to start the result
- Click in the box of List Range go to the initial sheet and select your Data
- Click in the box of Criteria Range, go to where you wrote the 3 columns with Title and select the 6 cells (3 columns * 2 Rows)
- Click OK

  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I somewhat got it working. I actually wanted the OR function so I'm trying to use different rows... But it wont work! If I only do the director row it will properly do it, but anytime I try adding anything else it wont even take director out anymore

Comment: If you need to remove director and something else it means And

Comment: You are using <> different not = that is why it is And

Comment: I want to remove every listing with director OR president OR VP OR etc. 
      http://imgur.com/a/z9hjN That is not producing any results when I clearly have titles listed as VP, Director, President, etc. I even added * to the end of all of them

Comment: You don't have just the word Director alone write Director* VP* it will include all the word after it

Comment: write it the same way like in your Data not VP try my example it worked for me

Comment: don't write quotes "

Comment: Also it only removes the titles when Director is the first word! I need it to remove Director if its found Anywhere within "Title"!

Comment: try <>*Director*

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ltwwX  I tried that but again wont work. Some people's title is "Vice President" while others have "VP" so I have to include them both

Comment: make another column Title <> VP*

Comment: don't write *VP* it will remove any word that contains VP just write VP*

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 3 columns: *First, Last and Title*.

Here's another way to write the advanced filter:

[image: advanced filtering critera]

In words: if the Title does not have "Director" anywhere in it AND it doesn't have "Vice President" anywhere in it, filter out the row. Otherwise, show it.