# How to include an "AND" operator and Exclusions in AdvancedFilter with one criteria column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

First time poster so I apologize if there are any normal posting procedures that I miss.
I am trying to filter a large spreadsheet of data based on products' item codes.
Basically the file is a print out of product data and a usage statement below it, so the goal at this point is to be able to filter out the usage statements and different products if possible.

For reference: here are 6 lines of the column I want to filter:
[image]

I want to only show data for the 5 ...... 58 rows, excluding the 4 ..... 58 and the usages, &X00. &2P2.

Currently I have a criteria range on a different sheet, and input:
[image]

And it seems like the list acts as an "or" operator, it doesn't exclude the 4 NCNDNE 58 row like I would like.

```
Range(products).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
     criteriarange:=Worksheets("Criteria").Range(myrange)
```

Products being the column I'm filtering
myrange is the array on the other sheet that is being used as a filter.

Also for what it's worth, I did some reading that advancedfilter accepts "<>" as exclusions, but I have not gotten that to work.

Thanks in advance, I can post more of the code if needed, if it helps. I'm not a coder though, so I'm avoiding posting the whole thing because it'll definitely upset some people with its lack of elegance.

Comment: A single criteria of `5 * 58` (5[space][any text here][space]5) doesn't work?

Comment: It did! I was not aware wildcards worked like that.
Followup question, is there a way to exclude the NFNGNH criteria? or, say, anything that contains "NF"? 
It is complicated because there are dozens of combinations, so it would be easier to exclude than include all of the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (for example) include all rows which begin with `5`  and end with  `58` but do *not* contain `FFF` your filter range might look like this (side-by-side is AND'ing the criteria) :

[image]

Related: [Exclusion Filtering in Excel Advanced Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332435/exclusion-filtering-in-excel-advanced-filter)

Comment: It won't let me upvote your comment, but thank you, Tim!